# How to add summernote wysiwyg editor in Vue

Tags: vue.js, summernote

Can one add summernote in a Vue component? I've tried to check online how to do so but my efforts have been futile. Kindly assist me on how to do it or a link where I can check out how to do it. Thanks

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="send">
    <input type="text" v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
      console.log(this.title);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Eugene82/qnayovjw/ here you can find working fiddle